# php file upload not moving to target directory permission issue ubuntu apache

Tags: php, apache

I have tried to upload a file but it's not uploading to the target
 directory. Also, I have given permission 755 but still it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Linux operating system you have to set the default apache user and group in its configuration file. That is apache2.conf

Steps 
1. vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2. set user and group to your machine account user and group
3. then save it
4. then restart apache (service apache2 restart)

For example
User vijay
Group vijay